# Thread.Sleep() in .NET Core on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, .net-mac

I'm working with .NET Core on my Mac machine.

Somewhere in my code I want to use this code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

But it can not find `Thread` in `System.Threading` namespace.

What's wrong? Isn't `Thread` available for Mac, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Meh, don't hold your breath for it.  This was dropped long before CoreFx was started. Task.Delay() is the way forward, it is the Right Way™

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Isn't `Thread` available for Mac?

Not yet: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576

> The current System.Threading.Thread (and System.Threading.ThreadPool) packages only support desktop and CoreCLR.

and: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576#issuecomment-187184341

> I can see that the latest System.Threading.Thread package in the dotnet-core NuGet feed hasn't changed this picture.

Comment: Reading the issue2576 it will be available in rc2, and rc2 will be expected to ship soon

Comment: @Eldho Hence why I said "not yet" :)

Comment: Yes, just confirming it

Comment: But that issue is about UWP, not about OSX.

Answer (score 12):

Do you have [System.Threading.Thread](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Thread/) package added to your `project.json`?

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811",
        "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

Then I can use `Thread.Sleep`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;


    namespace ConsoleApplication
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]